# How can I convert char* buffer to unsigned char buffer

Tags: c++, image-processing, gtk3, taglib

I have got this code to save image from buffer:

```
   FILE * fout;      
  fopen_s(&fout, "output.jpg", "wb");
  fwrite(pictureFrame->picture().data(), pictureFrame->picture().size(), 1, fout);
```

In this way I save cover art using taglib.
The "pictureFrame->picture().data()" is char* buffer;

I've just tried to display cover art in gtk+ window. But I've recieved error - argument of type char* is incompatible with parameter of type "const guchar*".

I know, I have to convert char* buffer to unsigned char buffer, but I don't know how. Can anybody help me?

```
pixbuf_loader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new ();
gdk_pixbuf_loader_write (pixbuf_loader, pictureFrame->picture().data(), pictureFrame->picture().size(), NULL);
```

[Link to gdk_pixbuf_loader documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/unstable/GdkPixbufLoader.html#gdk-pixbuf-loader-write)

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`. Or you could just copy the whole thing but that's very needlessly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're down in the dirt, you just *have* to get dirty!  Something like (yuk!):

```
fwrite(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pictureFrame->picture().data()), pictureFrame->picture().size(), 1, fout);
```