# C++ make unsigned char * buffer from string

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

I have this string.

```
char * data = "A1B2C3D4E5F6A7B8";
```

Here each A1 B2 C3 D4 E5 F6 A7 B8 will be bytes for unsigned char* buffer.

My concern is how to convert the data into unsigned char* buffer.

```
unsigned char* buffer;
buffer = (unsigned char*)data;
```

I will use the buffer for a parameter of a function like this to write the data into memory.

```
int abc(uint64_t address, buffer, uint32_t lenght);
```

Can anyone please give me a correct way?

Comment: `char * data = "A1B2C3D4E5F6A7B8";` is not allowed. `data` must be `const char*`. What does buffer mean here? Do you allocate memory for it somewhere?

Comment: Yes I will allocate memory with the buffer.

Comment: But `buffer` now doesn't point to any allocated memory, it points to the string literal, after your edit of the question.

Comment: [**How can I convert char* buffer to unsigned char buffer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098264/how-can-i-convert-char-buffer-to-unsigned-char-buffer) seems apropos.

Comment: Do you mean converting "A1B2C3D4E5F6A7B8" to {0xA1, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xD4,...}?

Comment: What does " convert the data into unsigned char* buffer" mean?

Comment: What error are you meet? Could you post the error code? I remember for many of system, `char` would be considered to be `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a demo about the char* buffer, unsigned char* and string.

```
// test.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun(unsigned char* pt) {
   cout<<*pt<<*(pt+1)<<endl;  // print first and second element
}
int main(){
    char Data[] = "abcde";       // a string with 6 elements stored in char array.
    char* data = Data;           // char pointer point to the char array
    unsigned char* buffer;       // declare an unsigned char
    buffer = (unsigned char*) data;  // buffer points to the same address data pointed.
    fun(buffer);                 // function requires an unsigned char pointer
    return 0;
}
```

The output

```
ab
```

To compile and run

```
g++ -Wall test.cpp;
./a.out
```

---

P.S.

> `char * data = "A1B2C3D4E5F6A7B8";`

The above line would cause a warning when compiling because the string is immutable. Better changes it to `char const * data = "A1B2C3D4E5F6A7B8";`

Comment: I like the -Wall part

Comment: Thanks for reply. but my actual concern is That A1 B2 is hexadecimal. if char * data is "0102" , it will be 0000000100000002 in binary.